# Delete last character and add new two characters in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, string, addition

I would like to delete last character from words from one column in MYSQL and directly add two new to the same word. For example I would like to change beiðni to beiðn|i.

> Here is my query = `UPDATE`ds_1_headword_backup1`SET`stem`=
>   CONCATE((SUBSTRING(`stem`,1, ,LENGTH(`stem`) - 2), '|i') WHERE`stem
>   `LIKE '%i' AND`gram_1_word_group`= 'f' AND`gram_2_endings`=
>   'indecl'`

Comment: Show your efforts first.

Comment: some sample query that you worked on please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
UPDATE ds_1_headword_backup1 SET stem = concat(substring(stem,1,length(stem)-1), '|i');
```

Example: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a646f/2/0)

Answer (score 1):

Here is complete sql query:

UPDATE `ds_1_headword_backup1` SET `stem` = CONCAT(SUBSTRING(`stem`,1,CHAR_LENGTH(`stem`) - 1), '|i'), `gram_2_endings` = '(-i)' WHERE `stem` LIKE '%i' AND `gram_1_word_group` = 'f' AND `gram_2_endings` = 'indecl'

The difference is in using `char_length`

Answer (score 1):

I agree with chejnik, but don't have enougth reputation to comment his variant, so create another one.

You should use CHAR_LENGTH instead of LENGTH, because CHAR_LENGTH returns **count of symbols**, but LENGTH - **sum of bytes**.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/46248)

So, 7alhashmi answer is correct only for strings, which have 1 byte per character.